# AngularJS directive watch validity

Tags: angularjs

I try to create a directive which should peform some actions when an input field is marked as invalid. For this example lets assume I have a directive which checks if the input is a prime number, and I want to create a directive which adds a class to the element when it's invalid:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="primeNumber" validate-prime invalid-add-class="error">
```

The validate-prime uses the parsers and formatters on ng-model to update the validity of the model.

Now I want the invalid-add-class directive to add the class "error" when the model is invalid, and to remove it when it is valid. In other words, it should watch the $valid (or $invalid) property of the model controller. However, I can't figure out how to get this working. I tried:

```
link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    ctrl.$watch("$valid", function(newVal, oldVal) {
    //never fired
    });
}
```

Perhaps I could watch some variable on scope, but I don't know which variable to watch for.

So how can I be notified when the validity of a model changes?

Comment: if you can share your directive it will be nice!

Comment: I don't remember what I exactly used this for, but CaioToOn's second solution is pretty much the entire link function already. Only the body of the second function should be filled with whatever action you want to when the validity changes.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you have a `<form>`, add a `name` to it (lets assume 'myForm') and a `name` to your input (lets assume `myInput`). You should be able to `$watch` this by:

```js
scope.$watch('myForm.myInput.$valid', function(validity) {})
```

If you don't have a `form`, you can always watch a function. This way:

```js
scope.$watch(function() { return ctrl.$valid; }, function(validity){});
```

You can read more about the form approach [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form).

Answer (score 12):

If you do not have a `<form />`you can easily get one:

In your directive definition:

```
require: '^form'
```

and then in your link function, the form is passed as the fourth parameter:

```
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
```

Now you don't have to hard-code the form or the input field to perform the $watch:

```
 scope.$watch(ctrl.$name + '.' + element.attr('name') + '.$valid', 
 function (validity) {});
```

Comment: This was perfect. Although for some reason I had to use `ctrl[0].$name` - not sure why my control was returning an array of 1 form though...

Comment: it will return an array if the 'require' attribute is passed an array (I suspect it is for you)

Answer (score 7):

Our goal, in general, should be to make a directive work independently of any one form or input. How can we allow it to read the local `$valid` property without imperatively binding it to a single specific form & input name?

Just use `require: 'ngModel'` as one of the properties of your directive config. This will inject the local ngModel controller as the fourth argument to the link function, and you can place a `$watch` directly upon `$valid` without needing to couple the directive's implementation to any particular form or input.

```
require: 'ngModel',
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
    scope.inputCtrl = controller;
    scope.$watch('inputCtrl.$valid', handlerFunc)
}
```

The handler should consistently fire on changes to $valid with that structure. See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmlilley/2mvLr/6/), where the input is validated for the pattern of a U.S. Zip-Code or Zip+4. You'll get an alert each time validity changes.

EDIT 3/21/14: This post previously got hung up on a delusion of mine, fixating on the wrong cause of an implementation problem. My fault. The example above removes that fixation. Also, added the fiddle, showing that this approach does in fact work, and always did, once you add quotes around the watch expression.

Comment: Are you sure this works? Because to me it seems that `inputCtrl.$valid` would be evaluated once (when the link function is executed) and that the result is passed to `scope.$watch`. So that would mean that the actual call would be either `scope.$watch(true, handlerFunc)` or `scope.$watch(false, handlerFunc)`, both of which doesn't result in a variable being watched.

Comment: `inputCtrl.$valid` is a reference to a property of an object, not a primitive value. It will be evaluated as such each time the `$watch` fires. I've got it working on personal projects, but don't currently have a good public demo available.

Comment: AFAIK `inputCtrl.$valid` IS a primitive. It is either `true`, `false` or `undefined`, all of which are primitives. You cannot create references to properties of objects, only to objects themselves in Javascript. See also this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Mh92/2/. As you can see, your code does not trigger the callback, only with quotes it does. This is again because you cannot create a reference to any primitive. By putting quotes around `inputCtrl.$valid` you instruct angular to evaluate that expression in the current scope, and thus it works.

Comment: As for your `require: 'ngModel'` story I don't think I fully follow you. AFAIK `require` does not alter the scope, but passes the controller of the required directive as the 4th parameter of the link function. Your scope still won't have a `$valid` property. So the problem is not that you're watching a primitive value, the problem is that the value simply doesn't exists.

Comment: @Tiddo, you're absolutely correct about how the require property works. That was a total brain-fart of mine, probably owing to exhaustion. That said, simply adding quotes around the watch expression in that example would have fixed it. I've made updates, including a Fiddle showing it in action. Please let me know if anything's amiss.

Comment: I think this won't work in case you have several watchers like this in one scope (name conflict). Instead of adding extra variable to scope you can just watch function: `scope.$watch(function() { return controller.$valid; }, handlerFunc)`.

Comment: Having "require: 'ngModel'" would pass the input element it self not the controller.