# Angular - on invalid field, fire method?

Tags: angularjs

When my field becomes invalid, is there a way to fire a method in my js?

So for example, the user fails to fill out the name field, clicks submit, I want to:

```
console.log('they forgot');
```

Thanks

Comment: Its very impressive, maybe I noob but I didnt understand what you want. Please post relevant code, problem and expected result

Comment: Here I think is an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15902947/514463

Answer (score 0):

There is a $error object made available by AngularJS. This object contains all of the validations on a particular form and tells if they are valid or invalid.

To get access to this property, we can use the following syntax:

```
formName.inputfieldName.$error
```

[Here is a jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/8zavK/3/)

[This document](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html) is a good reference for  understanding form-validations using AngularJS.

Also, for dealing with custom validations, you can add your own directives. A sample of making such directives is given in the link above.