# AngularJS input watch $valid or $error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to `$watch` the `$error` or the `$valid` value of a control. This is the control:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm"> 
  <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInputMdl" business-validation/>
</form>
```

`business-validation` is a custom directive that alters the validity of the control. I've attempted the following approaches (using either `$valid` or `$error`) based on what I've read at [AngularJS directive watch validity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899389/angularjs-directive-watch-validity):

1. This does not work since `$valid` does not exist on `myForm.myInput`.

   ```
   $scope.$watch('myForm.myInput.$valid', function (isValid) {
     $scope.usefulVariable = step3.CreditCardNumber.$valid;
   },true);
   ```
2. This does not work since `validity.valid` apparently cannot be watched.

   ```
   $scope.$watch('myForm.myInput.validity.valid', function (isValid) {
     $scope.usefulVariable = step3.CreditCardNumber.$valid;
   },true);
   ```
3. This does not work since `$scope.myInputMdl` is not watched on every change.

   ```
   $scope.$watch('$scope.myInputMdl', function (isValid) {
     $scope.usefulVariable = step3.CreditCardNumber.$valid;
   },true);
   ```

Can't the validity be watched from a controller?

**EDIT**

I'm not trying to write or edit `business-validation` directive. What I'm trying is to `$watch` `$valid` or `$error` from form's controller.

**EDIT 2**

Controller's code is:

```
app.controller('WizardBusinessActionCtrl',
   function ($scope, $http, $parse, $filter, wizardBusinessActionService, $timeout) {
     //controller code
   }
);
```

Comment: The first approach should work: http://plnkr.co/edit/LIJTj7gpz5A0yB917uxh?p=preview. And you don't the `true` for deep watch

Comment: @NewDev your approach works perfectly, but if I assign that value with an input, the input doesn't get updated.

Comment: which input are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason why your first variant shouldn't work.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="MainController">
        <form name="myForm"> 
            <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInputMdl" business-validation />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller and directive:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('myForm.myInput.$valid', function (validity) {
        console.log('valid', validity);
    });
});

myApp.directive('businessValidation', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            function validate (input) {
                return input === 'hello';
            }

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                var valid = validate(value);
                ctrl.$setValidity('businessValidation', valid);
                return valid ? value : undefined;
            });

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('businessValidation', validate(value));
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

`$valid` property value will change when `myInput` validity changes, and `$watch` callback will be fired.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/287/

Comment: Sorry, I should have warned that the problem is not at the directive per se, but at the controller... let me correct that please...

Comment: Added. I do not know if it is enought code for the question, but consider a minimal working controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. [Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dvgpSiH23mYiTuA7lyaK?p=preview)

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="userForm" novalidate >
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="firstName" required />
  </form>
  <div>{{firstName}}</div>
  <input type = 'button'  value = 'Submit' ng-click ='validateInput()'/>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
 angular.module('getterSetterExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.validateInput = function(){
      $scope.$watch($scope.userForm.userName.$valid, function() {
       if($scope.userForm.userName.$valid){
         alert('Value is True');
       }
       else{
         alert('Value is False');
       }
      });

    }

  }]);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have warned that the problem is not at the directive per se, but at the controller...

Comment: Do you want to validate any input from controller using `$valid`??

Comment: what I want is to assign the validity value of an input taken from `$error` or `$valid` to a variable in the scope.