# Why is this hidden field not updated when `$watch` is used on the controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this form:

`business-validation` is a custom directive whose code is:

```
var CREDIT_CARD_REGEX = /^\d{0,24}$/;
angular.module('directives').directive('creditCard', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.creditCard, function (newValue) {
                    return ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);
                });
                return ctrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                    var newValue;
                    newValue = ctrl.$modelValue;

                    element.validateCreditCard(function (result) {
                        if (result.card_type &&
                                result.luhn_valid &&
                                result.length_valid &&
                                CREDIT_CARD_REGEX.test(element.val())) {
                            element.attr("data-card-type", result.card_type.name);
                            ctrl.$setValidity('creditCard', true);
                            newValue = viewValue;
                        }
                        else {
                            element.removeAttr("data-card-type");
                            ctrl.$setValidity('creditCard', false);
                        }
                    }, { accept: ['visa', 'mastercard'] });

                    return newValue;
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

I need the value of `myForm.anInputName.$error.creditCard` at the controller and for that purpose I've made [this attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475700/angularjs-input-watch-valid-or-error) and also something like:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="IsCreditCardValid" name="IsCreditCardValid" value="myForm.anInputName.$error.creditCard" />
```

and

```
$scope.$watch("IsCreditCardValid", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    alert('theChangeHasBeen:' + oldValue + ' -> ' + newValue);
});
```

In order to `$watch` `IsCreditCardValid` at the controller.

This paragraph is shown:

```
<p class="help-block" ng-if="smyForm.anInputName.$error.creditCard && !myForm.anInputName.$error.required">Wrong credit card number!</p>
```

but the hidden input never gets the expected value although using the same condition. Why this last hidden field doesn't get updated and the `$watch` in never triggered?

**EDIT**
If I do

```
myForm.anInputName.$valid: {{myForm.anInputName.$valid}}
```

The value is updated on screen, but the hidden field doesn't change its value.

Comment: suggest you create a simplified demo ( one that doesn't require credit card number)

Comment: @charlietfl I'm currently in a hurry... but I'll do as you said ASAP...

Comment: @charlietfl I added an edit, that gives you any hint?

Comment: did you ever try `ng-model="myForm.anInputName.$valid"` and remove the `value`?

Comment: @charlietfl how could I reference that at the controller? I mean, `IsCreditCardValid` is the model I want to populate... let my try...

Comment: you can access all the properties of `myForm` in controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74593/discussion-between-jpcf-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

`ngModel` works only on [listed input types](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel), and hidden isn't among them. The internals of `input` directive make a hint that it won't work automatically on every possible input:

```
var inputType = {

  ...

  'hidden': noop,
  'button': noop,
  'submit': noop,
  'reset': noop,
  'file': noop
}
```

This makes sense because hidden inputs don't need two-way binding (they are unnecessary in Angular app, too). If you want to use them anyway, then

```
<input type="hidden" name="IsCreditCardValid" value="{{ IsCreditCardValid }}" />
```

Comment: I've tried [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479977/why-is-this-hidden-field-not-updated-when-watch-is-used-on-the-controller?noredirect=1#comment47121975_29479977)  but it does not work...

Comment: I guess you have problems besides the subject, and they don't seem to be solvable when you post single lines of code without further context.