# AngularJS validation directive - formController not bound

Tags: validation, angularjs-directive

To simplify my form validation, I try to go from this:

```html
<div ng-class="{'field--error': form.firstname.$error.maxlength && form.firstname.$dirty}" class="field">
  <label for="firstname" class="field__label">Firstname</label>  
  <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firsname" ng-model="formData.firstname" ng-maxlength="32" class="field__input">
</div>
```

to this:

```html
<div field-error="{fieldName: 'firsname'}" class="field">
  <label for="firstname" class="field__label">Firstname</label>  
  <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firsname" ng-model="formData.firstname" ng-maxlength="32" class="field__input">
</div>
```

I used a fieldError directive to make validation easier (especially dirty and touched). The directive gets a reference to the formController via the '^form' param:

```js
.directive('fieldError', function fieldError(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^form',
        scope: {
            fieldError: '='
        },
        link: function( scope, elem, attrs, formCtrl ) {
            var 
                fieldInput = formCtrl[ scope.fieldError.fieldName ],
                isInError = false;

            if ( fieldInput && fieldInput.$dirty ) {
                // validation process goes here
            }

            if ( isInError ) {
                elem.addClass('field--error');
            } else {
                elem.removeClass('field--error');
            }
        }
    };
})
```

**Issue:** the link function isn't called when typing text in the input.
Maybe I have to use a watcher, but I heard this is bad practice.

**EDIT**

following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899389/angularjs-directive-watch-validity) I updated my directive:

```js
link: function( scope, elem, attrs, formCtrl ) {
 var fieldInputPath = formCtrl.$name + '.' + scope.fieldError.fieldName + '.$invalid';

 // fieldInputPath = 'form.firstname.$invalid'

 scope.$watch( fieldInputPath, function( n, o ) {
     // never fired
 } );
}
```

But the watcher is never fired. I put a breakpoint in devtool, fieldInputPath is good.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Ofc nothing happens if you haven't got anything that checks for changes..

Comment: By "checks for changes", did you mean add a watcher?

Comment: Yes, a watcher is perfect for checking for input changes. It's bad practice to have too many on a page, but one won't matter.

Comment: Ok, so let's take the watcher. Tx!