# Monitor for $valid on input element in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I have this directive that prepends an `<i>` element before each `<input>` element with `add-icon-element` attribute. Now what i'm trying to do is to observe validation for each `<input>` element, so when the user types something in one of them the class of the `<i>` element that precedes will  change to `fa-check green-i`.  I tried to do it by using `attrs.$observe` to see when the class changes from `ng-invalid` to `ng-valid` but it fires only one time when the DOM is structured, it doesn't react to changes in the `input` element.

What am i doing wrong? is there a way to do it using the input `$valid`?
I saw some answers regarding one `input` with suggestions to add names to the `form` and `input` - but what can I do if I have multiple `inputs` that I need to validate and not just one?

```
angular.module('mean.theme')
.directive("addIconElement", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function (scope, inputElement, attrs) {
            var $icon = $('<i class="fa"></i>');
            inputElement.before($icon);
            attrs.$observe('class', function(val){
                if (val.indexOf("ng-valid") >= 0) {
                    inputElement.prev().addClass('fa-check green-i');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and this is one of my 'inputs' in the html:

```
<form role="form" name="createProjectForm" class="form-validation">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label text-center center-block" for="project.name">
                Name Your Project
        </label>
        <div class="input-icon right">
            <input type="text" placeholder="type here" name="project.name"
                ng-model="project.name" required="required" class="form-control" add-icon-element/>
        </div>
    </div>
<form>
```

Comment: how your directive html looks like??

Comment: @PankajParkar yes, sorry, i added the html..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need create a directive for such case, you could achieve this by using `ng-class` directive, only change your field name from `name="project.name"` to `name="project_name"`

```
<div class="input-icon right">
    <input type="text" placeholder="type here" name="project.name" 
       ng-class="{'fa-check green-i': createProjectForm.project_name.$valid}"
       ng-model="project.name" required="required" 
       class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

**Update**

To make it generic way, you need to `require` ngModel directive on that element, which will give you access to the `ngModelController`.

```
angular.module('mean.theme')
.directive("addIconElement", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'ngModel', //require to get access to `ngModelController`
        link: function (scope, inputElement, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var $icon = $('<i class="fa"></i>');
            inputElement.before($icon);
            scope.$watch(function(){
               return ngModelCtrl.$valid; //made watch on field validation.
            }, function(val){
                if (val.indexOf("ng-valid") >= 0) {
                    inputElement.prev().addClass('fa-check green-i');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i need to apply the class "fa-check green-i" to the <i> tag that was placed before that input. and also, i have multiple inputs, so i need something more generic for all of them instead of addressing each one in particular. any idea..?

Comment: perfect answer, thanks a lot! i'm pretty new to angular and was searching a solution for 2 hours... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23871934/1636157

```
angular.module('mean.theme')
.directive("addIconElement", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '^form',
        link: function (scope, inputElement, attrs, ctrl) {
            var $icon = $('<i class="fa"></i>');
            inputElement.before($icon);

            scope.$watch(ctrl.$name + '.' + inputElement.attr('name') + '.$valid', function (valid) {
               if(valid) {
                  inputElement.prev().addClass('fa-check green-i');
               } else {
                  inputElement.prev().removeClass('fa-check green-i');
               }
            }); 
        }
    };
});
```